# I would like to know how by doing a simple click on a div I want get his ID

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project in Javascript.

I would like to know how to get the ID of a element with a click.

This is my code:

```
const cercleEl = document.querySelectorAll(".cercle");

cercleEl.forEach((element) => {
  const elementId = element.getAttribute("id");
});
document.addEventListener("click", cercleEl);
```

Comment: Add an HTML example.

Comment: `cercleEl` is a NodeList, you can't use a nodelist as an event handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
    console.log(ev.target.id)
});
```

`ev.target` is the element you click on. Thus, you can easily find it's id by using `ev.target.id`. There is no need to create a list of all elements ID's at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. You need to add ,`addEventListener` to Particular elements in `forEach` loop

```js
const cercleEl = document.querySelectorAll(".cercle");

cercleEl.forEach((element) => {
   element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"))

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="cercle" id="a">
  <h1>hi</h1>
</div>


<div class="cercle" id="b">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: ty its working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.circle').forEach(function(element) {
   element.addEventListener('click', () => {
     console.log(element.id);
   });
 });
```